# How to hide graphic items in turtle while they are loading

Tags: python, performance, graphics

I am looking for a way to load all of the graphics for a click adventure game without the user seeing them load on the screen.

hide turtle
Start/splash screen

I have several graphic layers.  The first one is a room with nothing in it, and then I have the layers added on top that will hide and show depending on where the user clicks.  The issue I am having is that the layer with nothing on it shows up while it is loading and then all of the components show up afterwards.  This shows the user the blank room first and then they know which components are clickable because when the game starts it is populated with the items (many layers) which weren't there with the initial start screen.

An example :
A bare room.
Layer one is a barrel
Layer two is a sign on the wall.

When the game starts, the bare room is loaded - it shows nothing but the bare room.  When the two turtle objects are loaded in afterward, they show up.  Because the loading of all graphics is not instant, the user can see the objects that are obviously not a part of the original bare room (the barrel and the sign on the wall are clickable and move), therefore alerting the user that they are clickable objects instead of having to click and find out themselves.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I was thinking about adding a splash screen to start (therefore all of the graphics would be loaded behind it), but I am unsure how to accomplish this.

Comment: I should also indicate this is turtle graphics using python.